# std::ofstream in global operator new

Tags: c++, logging, new-operator, ofstream, dynamic-allocation

Is there a way to write to a file within a replaced global operator new?

```
// simple operator new replacment
void* operator new(std::size_t bytes) {
    std::ofstream log{"log.txt"};
    log << bytes << " bytes allocated\n";
    return std::malloc(bytes);
}
```

std::ofstream uses new, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea, but you might be able to work around it if you know *where* `std::ofstream` uses `new`. Does it do it in the constructor or when opening the file? Then you can just open the file before the first `new` is called. If it happens in the `<<` operator then perhaps uses fixed-size strings (arrays) and use `snprintf` to format the output and `write` the output to the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the operator but for specific parameters, I mean not the global one, 
Here an example for a class called student :

```
 void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl;
    void * p = ::new student(); 
    //void * p = malloc(size); will also work fine

    return p;
}
```

you can find more details [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-new-delete-operator-c/)